# How to build \external\mmc-util\ and execute it in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a RK3288 SOC platform and its all AOSP source code(Andorid SDK, NDK, Linux kernel, U-boot).

There is *\external\mmc-util\mmc.c* in AOSP.
That seems to use `ioctl` function to test eMMC device by different eMMC command

I want to build and execute it in the SOC platform.

Refer [Adding a new program to build](http://www.charleswilde.com/android-native-development-using-the-android-open-source-project/), but enter mm will get following:

```
fatal error: #include asm-generic/int-ll64.h: No such file or directory
fatal error: #include <linux/mmc/ioctl.h>: No such file or directory
```

My purpose is designed a program, that can send some eMMC command to test eMMC device in SOC platform.

So I think some .c files in */external/mmc-util* folder can help me.
These files use `ioctl` function to send command to eMMC device, they are like sample code.

It should be executed through ADB or include in Android system image, isn't?

How can I build(make) it success for running in Android?

I don't know how to solve and do next step.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (for Linux and Eclipse ADT) is:

1. Take the hello-jni example; make sure it compiles (via `ndk-build`) and runs.
2. In the jni/ subdirectory, locate Android.mk
3. Modify it to compile your file.

Example *Android.mk*:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) # magic spell

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := one
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += one.c ... # files to compile
# link with liblog.so libMyStuff.so libTheirStuff.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib -lMyStuff -lTheirStuff
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)    # this builds libone.so


# you can build more than one module via the same .mk
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := sendraw
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sendRawEth.c
#LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x -Wall         # whatever g++ flags you like
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog   # whatever ld flags you like

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)    # <-- Use this to build an executable.
```

Comment: If I don't want to use Eclipse, can I use arm-linux-androideabi to compile my program?

Comment: In general, yes; the following 2 links describe building iw and another tool which in fact does not work: https://z4ziggy.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/building-aircrack-ng-binaries-and-friends-for-android/  https://z4ziggy.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/how-to-run-aircrack-ng-on-your-android/ . If you manage to build iw, you will be able to reduce it to a hello-world.  BTW, you ***cannot*** use Eclipse/ADT for editing C/C++ source, it just creates a hello-world to start with.