# Cannot load library soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "log2f" referenced by "libvlfeat.so"

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk

I'm developing an Android application with native C is the core processing. I use NDKr10 to build libs from native code and success. But when I try to load the libs then the the error is shown:

`Cannot load library soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "log2f" referenced by "libvlfeat.so"...`

I found some resources say that this error caused by gcc compiler and Android target version, but I'm not sure about it.(My target SDK is 21).

**Update:** My app work fine on api 21 device but the lower version showing error.

Someone know about this problem?Please give me a solution to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vuong, did you ever manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must load the .so libraries in the order that would resolve dependencies between them. That is, you must hard-code the order of loading.

Some knowledge about Android.mk may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138372/755804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363021/multiple-my-and-3rd-party-native-libraries-in-android-ndk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043581/755804). (But if your project compiles successfully, your Android.mk is likely working.)

There is a gotcha that .so libraries in `libs/armeabi` and `libs/armeabi-v7a` do not get combined. That is, if you have some pre-compiled library only in the `armeabi` version, there is no use in compiling your libraries for `armeabi-v7a` (because the pre-compiled `armeabi` library will not be found).

Comment: I just test my app and it work fine on api 21 device but the lower version showing error.